# How to find armijo step length for a neural network?

Tags: optimization, python, numerics, neural-network

The armijo step length formula states that

```
f(x+lr*descent_direction) <=f(x)+c*lr*f_gradient*descent_direction
```

In the above formula lris the learning rate and f is the loss function. In a neural network setup, in order to find the armijo step length for the loss function, I need to calculate the loss on the updated model that is to find out f(x+lr*v). Now after I get the armijo step length from the formula, I need to update the model again with the revised lr(learning rate). Is it correct to update the model twice in each epoch? Or else how should I calculate the armijo step length?

Comment: To do that you would have to accumulate the gradient without changing the weights, then compute the residual sum for specifically updated weights. The problem is that often you are in a narrow valley situation, with 1 or a handful of dominant directions that keep the step size down, and thus also the adaptations in the non-dominant directions. So you need something like conjugate gradients or some other method to separate out the dominant directions to get a better descent direction.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

When computing the step length, you don't "update" the weights of the network. You just "test" whether certain updated weights would yield a certain result (that is, you are evaluating the objective function for updated weights), but you don't "commit" the updates. Only once you have determined the step length do you actually, irrevocably update the weights (i.e., you "commit" to the new weights).

You can implement the "test" step by storing the old weights, updating the weights, computing the objective function, and then replacing the new weights by the old, stored ones again.

Comment: How should I compute the value of the loss if I dont commit the new weights? I have to compute the step length for the loss function that computes the loss on the model. How to calculate the loss without updating or committing the weights? I am using PyTorch nn.BCELoss()

Comment: @Jeet: You could for instance use a second instance of the same network structure. In principle only one instance needs to be equipped for differentiation, so the second instance could be some per cent cheaper.

Comment: @Jeet Like I said in my last paragraph, the test stage can be done by setting the weights to new values, computing the loss function, and then setting them back to the old values.